# Retrieving values from multifield component in HTL in AEM 6.5

Tags: aem

I have a multifield component following this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Awards List"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/tabs"
            type="-nav"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <awards
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="Awards Properties"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <description
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textarea"
                                fieldLabel="Description"
                                name="./description"/>
                            <awards
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
                                composite="{Boolean}true"
                                fieldLabel="Awards">
                                <field
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container"
                                    name="./awards">
                                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                        <column
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                <awardtype
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
                                                    fieldDescription="Select Award Type"
                                                    fieldLabel="Award Type"
                                                    name="./type">
                                                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                        <gold
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            text="gold"
                                                            value="gold"/>
                                                        <silver
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            text="silver"
                                                            value="silver"/>
                                                        <bronze
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            text="bronze"
                                                            value="bronze"/>
                                                        <other
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            text="other"
                                                            value="other"/>
                                                    </items>
                                                </awardtype>
                                                <award
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                    fieldDescription="Name of Award"
                                                    fieldLabel="Award Name"
                                                    name="./award"/>
                                            </items>
                                        </column>
                                    </items>
                                </field>
                            </awards>
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </awards>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

And I'm trying to just output the contents of the multifield into a list.
And I'm attempting to do so with

```
<ul data-sly-list="${properties.awards}">
    <li>${item.type}</li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't render anything. As a test I did

```
<ul data-sly-list="${[1,2,3,4]}">
    <li>${item}</li>
</ul>
```

Which did work. Looking online I found resources like https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem65_coral_resourcetypes.html#UseaDataSourceObjecttopopulateaSelectfield

But they seem to be using Java classes to generate the multifield and I'm hoping that's not necessary. I don't need any extra logic all I'm trying to do is display the values of the fields.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Does using multifields require making a Java class to handle it?

EDIT: I've tried getting the content using a javascript object by having a js file with the contents

```
"use strict";

use(function () {
    var description = granite.resource.properties["description"];
    var awards = granite.resource.properties["awards"];

    return {
        description: description,
    };
});
```

and using

```
<div data-sly-use.awardsObject="awardslist.js">
    <p>
        ${awardsObject.description}
        ${awardsObject.awards}
    </p>
</div>
```

But I can't get awards to return anything. I've tried stringifying the awards object to see if I get any data, but I get none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because you are using a composite multifield (look at the property `composite="{Boolean}true"` against the multifield) which generally handles the form content as composite and creates child nodes under the current component to hold the property values.

[Quoting from the docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield/index.html)

> true to handle the form content value as composite.
>
> Composite multifield supports nesting another multifield (composite or
>   not). However, non-composite one doesn’t support nesting.
>
> For example, given the name property of field is addresses, and the
>   descendant fields have following name property values:

```
street1
street2  
postcode 
city/name 
city/state  
city/country/name
gps/lat 
gps/long
```

> it would save the following structure in the repository:

```
 + addresses   + item0
     - street1
     - street2
     - postcode
     + city
       - name
       - state
       + country
         - name
     + gps
       - lat
       - long   + item1
     - street1
     - street2
     - postcode
     + city
       - name
       - state
       + country
         - name
     + gps
       - lat
       - long
```

Since the `properties` object only holds the properties of the current resource, `${properties.awards}` would be null and hence it doesn't display anything.

It would be easier to create either a Sling Model or Java / Javascript Use API class to get the list and then use it in the HTL file.

Sample JS Use API

```
"use strict";

use(function () {
    var awards = resource.getChild("awards").listChildren();

    return {
        awards: awards,
    };
});
```

Sample HTL code

```
<sly data-sly-use.children="children.js">
    <ul data-sly-list.award="${children.awards}">
        <li>${award.type}</li>
    </ul>
<sly>
```

Kindly note that the `properties` object, which is an instance of [ValueMap](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html) only returns the properties of the current resource. Since the multifield values are stored as child resources, you need to access the child resource first before accessing its properties.

Comment: I tried using a javascript use class and I am able to get it to work with other fields but I'm not sure how to use it with a multifield. I used     var awards = granite.resource.properties["awards"]; but I wasn't able to get any data from that. I updated my question with more details.

Comment: @Matt, updated the answer with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic sling model that returns a list of composite multifield items is ideal since it accepts a node name parameter.

```
package com.myproject.core.models;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class, adapters = MultiField.class)
public class MultiField {

    private Iterator<Resource> nodesItemList;

    @Inject
    private String multifieldNodeName;

    @Inject
    private Resource resource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void activate() {
        nodesItemList = Collections.emptyIterator();

        Resource multiFieldNode = resource.getChild(multifieldNodeName);
        if (multiFieldNode != null) {
            nodesItemList = multiFieldNode.listChildren();
        }
    }

    public Iterator<Resource> getItemsList() {
        return nodesItemList;
    }

}
```

Using this sling model requires a node name parameter to return a list of child nodes. For example, use ${'com.myproject.core.models.MultiField' @ multifieldNodeName='awards'} given your dialog .content multifield field name ./awards as shown here:

```
<div data-sly-use.awards="${'com.myproject.core.models.MultiField' @ multifieldNodeName='awards'}"
    data-sly-test="${awards}" class="panel-container"
    data-sly-list.awards="${awards.itemsList}">
    <div>${awards.type @ context='html'}</div>
    <div>${awards.award @ context='html'}</div>
</div>
```

For more information and an example, see my [Multifield Component](https://jimfrenette.com/aem/components/multifield-component/) blog post.